# firefox addon context menu label

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

```
context_menu.Item({
    label: "Search",
    context: context_menu.SelectionContext(),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("my_scripts/post_messages.js")],
    onMessage: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'context') {
            var text = get_selected_text();
            if (text.length > 2) {
                this.label = 'Search "' + text + '"';
            } else {
                this.label = "";
            }
        }
        if (msg == 'click') {
            var filename = 'selected_word.txt';
            var str = get_selected_text();
            saveText(filename, str);
        }
    },
});
```

Above is part of my code. The problem is when this.label is set to be "", the right-click menu shows an empty label, but I don't want that to be shown. I know this can be done if the self.on('context', ...); function returns false, but I don't know how to send a message to the content script.

By the way, the get_selected_text() function is better defined in addon script using "sdk/selection", so it is not defined in the content script.

So how to send a message(the selection) to the content script, or is it possible?
Or what exactly happens after self.on('context', ...); function returning false to make the lable not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a solution, not perfect but enough for me.

```
var selection_workers = [];
tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
    var worker = tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: [data.url("my_scripts/receive_post_messages.js"),],
    });
    selection_workers.push(worker);
});

selection.on('select', function() {
    var obj = {
        text: get_selected_text(),
        url: tabs.activeTab.url,
    };
    for (var i in selection_workers) {
        var worker = selection_workers[i];
        worker.port.emit('selected_text', obj);
    }
});
```

Then, save the selected text as a body attribute, so I can do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out. I use a style sheet to make display none whenever a label is found with the unique value `dont show this label unique ya ya`.

So now instead of setting it to blank set it to `labelValToHide`.

```
var {Cc, Ci} = require('chrome');
var sss = Cc['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
var labelValToHide = "dont show this label unique ya ya";
var css = "label[value='" + tempHold + "'] { display:none; }";
var newURIParam = {
    aURL: 'data:text/css,' + encodeURIComponent(css),
    aOriginCharset: null,
    aBaseURI: null
}
cssUri = Services.io.newURI(newURIParam.aURL, newURIParam.aOriginCharset, newURIParam.aBaseURI);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, myServices.sss.AUTHOR_SHEET);

context_menu.Item({
    label: "Search",
    context: context_menu.SelectionContext(),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("my_scripts/post_messages.js")],
    onMessage: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'context') {
            var text = get_selected_text();
            if (text.length > 2) {
                this.label = 'Search "' + text + '"';
            } else {
                this.label = labelValToHide;

            }
        }
        if (msg == 'click') {
            var filename = 'selected_word.txt';
            var str = get_selected_text();
            saveText(filename, str);
        }
    },
});


//on unload of addon run this:
//myServices.sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, myServices.sss.AUTHOR_SHEET);
```